# How to execute "javac and java commands" from java program?

Tags: java, javac

Is there any way to execute "javac and java commands" from java program?
If so,please help me out....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac ...");` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` to do this. But there're some common traps that you take care of. This article on ["When Runtime.exec() won't"](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) work correctly highlights some of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class

```
 ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("javac", "arg1, "arg2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/ instead of attempting to execute javac. It gives you much more control and returns usable information

Comment: See [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I know Open the explorer：`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer");`
so I guess `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java");` and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac");`
You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html), It provides a simple API. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to run by invoking os shell and then by passing javac and java tools.

take the result by using inputstream and print it