# Compiling JAR with UTF8

Tags: java

Is it possible to compile a jar file so that it already "remembers" to be run with UTF-8 encoding?

My JAR works correctly when it is run from CMD with specifying the encoding:

```
java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar "C:\(...)\ZBook 14\Desktop\Server.jar"
```

I would rather have the file remembered the setting. I do not want to modyfy my default environmental JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

Comment: I would just explicitly specify the character set everywhere in your code. Anything that uses the system default is brittle IMO.

Comment: I already tried that but that is not a solution. I need a separate code for UTF-16 etc.

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding an example of code which is affected by this.

Comment: I am having troubles to set encoding to HermiT reasoner. But I also need it to my other jars to set more complex settings than only utf-8. All of them work fine from CMD, but I would prefere them to remember the prefered settings

Comment: If your file encoding needs to be passed as a parameter always then it may be better to add a script to execute java command or an `ini` file to accept encoding as a parameter to run your jar.

Comment: Could you please write me full example of how to do it (how the JAR knows about ini file to start with)? This is problably the solution.

Comment: this may be OS dependent. you may need to write a .bat or .sh file to run the java command. 

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804020/create-a-shell-script-to-run-a-java-program-on-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938944/how-to-run-java-application-by-bat-file

Comment: I see... :(, .bat  file is not much better than CMD for me

Comment: basically you will have to combine 2 solution. Read this thread how to params from `.ini` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318809/how-do-i-grab-an-ini-value-within-a-shell-script

Comment: if you are uncomfortable in writing a shell script then do this [run java command from a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402547/how-to-execute-javac-and-java-commands-from-java-program)

Comment: The last one is clever. In general it will be useful for me.

Comment: In manifest it is impossible to set encoding?

Comment: Well that is because there is no straight forward solution to passing params to java. We always have to tweek shell scripts to pass `JAVA_OPTS` and other params to java command.

Comment: passing a manifest file is used by `maven` and `ant`

Comment: Thank you very much for the discussion. I am still not sure how to solve my problem but you gave me a bunch of new ideas.

Comment: Note that you can also just call `System.setProperty` as the first thing you do in your `main` method, too...